# Post-apocalypse animated movie involving cyborg and enhanced humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, cyborg, cyberpunk

I watched this movie 5-6 years back, I remember the story but not the title. This movie starts in a train with an AI heavyweight cyborg and a girl, both return after completing a mission. This is an animated movie, and the animation looks like the one you find in games.

The cyborg clears out all non-essential tasks from his system as it runs out of battery. And all of a sudden, a few other cyborgs intercept their train which leads to a fight. Finally they return something to a gangster who is also a cyborg, who even has horns. He insists this duo to do another job, which can earn their freedom.

In the middle of the movie, they help two more people who are on another mission: an enhanced soldier and an Asian girl. In return, the soldier finds a malfunctioned disc in the robot, which eats up all his battery.

The girl is the key in the movie. Only she can activate a giant spider-like machine which can kill anyone in its way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Robot with horns", "robot and girl companion in a military setting", "game-like animation", it's an *Appleseed* movie.

Specifically, it's *Appleseed Alpha* (2014).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appleseed_Alpha):

> This film does not follow the previous *Appleseed* movie canon; it is an alternate version of the story's origins. Briareos, for example, is already a cyborg and did not become separated from Deunan to be later reunited in Olympus to join ESWAT.
>
> *Appleseed Alpha* depicts the early days of Deunan Knute and Briareos in the 22nd century. When they embark on a journey through the dystopic ruins of New York in search of the city of Olympus, they are hired by Two Horns, the warlord of the ruined city, to eliminate bipedal combat machines. During the fight, they befriend Iris and Olson and join them on their mission to prevent the malevolent cyborg Talos from capturing the humans' secret weapon, a gigantic war machine.

Comment: Oh good call. I should have remembered that. I read that manga when I was in high school, but I hadn't realized there was a CG version.

Comment: Exactly what iam looking for. Thanks @Jenayah.

Comment: Wow, that's… uh… straight up pure [cleavage window](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CleavageWindow) costume design right there.